# Union of 2 properties (1 single element, 1 array)

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to shape an API that has 1 success type & error types. I'd like for the types to be inferred, and the function to return a union of both the success & error types, something like:

```
import { Type } from '@nestjs/common';

interface CreateThingOptions<T extends Type<unknown> = Type<any>> {
  successType: T;
  errorTypes: T[]
}

declare function createThing<T>(options: CreateThingOptions<T>): ???

// given the function is called with:

createThing({
  successType: Post,
  errorTypes: [CreatePostError, ForbiddenError]
});

// the return type I'm looking for is:
// Post | CreatePostError | ForbiddenError
```

I'm not sure how to approach this... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would skip the interface and utilize the fact that `ArrayType[number]` returns a union of all the types contained in it:

```
declare function createThing<T, E extends readonly unknown[]>(options: {
    successType: T;
    errorTypes: E;
}): T | E[number];

// make some types for demonstration purposes
enum A { X }
enum B { X }
enum C { X }

// x has type A | B | C
const x = createThing({
    successType: A.X,
    errorTypes: [B.X, C.X]
});
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=4#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXzDigxABUALLVAcwB5SAaeAUXhAA8TVgBneI4HggBPeGgDWqHAHdUAbQC6APgAUOAA7Y8PAFzwA3gFgAUPDPweyMGBA8epYepB7SAbhPm2MGDhgOnuizuxgC+AJQu8AA+LHKoyAC2AEYgMArBJgD0mfAJUOIIPDgJCBiOtki+8KAJ2hgwxLj46sgw6jg8tiYg8QnwAIIG8AAa8CHdvfAAQkOj48Y9ifAAwrNjJlk57PDkUHxlTgPR08fLJmB18NsAvAREJBRU1CpGpuaW1rb25Xr9AHTDBgecypHx+cqBORTAFMZYAhQmcKuIA)